# google API with phalocon

Tags: phalcon, google-signin

I want to use google+ api with phalcon php framework.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener");
```

Before Call those Classes I want to import those classes . How can i do like this sort of things.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to require those classes would be to use composer to manage them:

inside your project root create composer.json and fill with:

```
"require": {
  "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta"
}
```

Then from the root directory run

```
$     composer install
```

Then in your bootstrap or index.php

```
/**
* Include composer autoloader
*/
require realpath('..') . "/vendor/autoload.php";
```

More information can be found at https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md